# Concurrent open TCP connections in WCF service

Tags: wcf, perfmon

We have a WCF service with multiple TCP endpoints.  I am interested in monitoring the total number of concurrent open connections at any given time.  Are there any perfmon counters that will allow us to do this out of the box?  Note that number of instances != number of connections in our case.

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer to use [PerfMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490957.aspx), have a look at [these performance counters](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windows2000serv/reskit/iisbook/c05_monitoring_tcp_connections.mspx?mfr=true).

Answer (score 2):

Use the netstat command to view open tcp connections

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490947.aspx